# R installed in wrong place

Tags: r

I have R 4.0.2 installed on my computer and would like to upgrade to the latest version (4.0.5). I am logged in on a personal account which is not an administrator. I got this message [A full R installation requires administrative priveleges, and it appears those are not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzuuR.png) and proceeded anyway. But I can only open 4.0.2 from the desktop or start menu, what should I do?

Comment: I'd recommend not using `updateR()` which is an unofficial function/package and downloading R directly from the R project website and using the official installer: https://cloud.r-project.org/

Comment: Without admin rights, the desktop symbol and registry entry can't be updated. You probably also don't have write permission in the programs directory. You'll need to use the Windows Explorer to navigate to the directory where you installed R. Then open rgui.exe.

Comment: I'd recommend uninstalling R completely from your system and then installing the updated version right from CRAN.

Comment: @DebarthaPaul I uninstalled R and installed it as administrator, it works now!